# How to implement web push notifications using FCM in php

Tags: php, push-notification, service-worker

I'm working on web push notifications using service worker. But I struck while sending notifications from server using FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging). Here is my php script and I'm not getting how should I call this in service worker. Please guide me.

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$msg = array(
               'message'       => 'Wakeup Wakeup!!',
               'title'         => 'Wakeup call !',
            );
$fields = array(
          'registration_id'  => xxxxxxxxxx,
          'data'              => $msg
         );
$headers = array
           (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, '//gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [web-push library for PHP](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php), which, as the name says, makes it easier to use the Web Push protocol via PHP.

Comment: I have gone through it but I did not get how to use it

Comment: how did you use this?

Comment: You can follow the documentation in the README of the repository, starting with the "Requirements" paragraph, then "Installation" and then "Usage".